# Three.js scene lighting from blender - Issues with distance and triangles

Tags: three.js, blender, lighting

I've got a question regarding the exporting of Blender scenes to be loaded into Three.js, with the focus on lighting.

We're using Blender to create our 3D environments, interiors in this case. In Blender the scenes look like they should. Here's an example I've put together with a single point light with Energy: 50 and Distance: 30. I've made these values so high so the problem is visible clearly inside Three.js. Here is a screen from blender:

[image: Point light in Blender]

Now, when exported using the Three.js exporter for Blender and imported using the SceneLoader, the result in Three.js is:

[image: Point light in Three.js]

Don't might the ugly brightness, the problem is the fact that it lights only parts of the scene. It looks like Three.js incorrectly lights different triangles of an object. Our 3D artist makes the objects in Blender using quads.

To make sure the problem lies not within the exporting and importing process, I've created a PointLight within Three with the same position, distance and brightness. This gives the exact same result as above.

I've tried using different lights as well. So far only the Sun light (Directional in Three) seems to give the correct result. The other lights don't work at all when exported from blender, but that is a problem outside of the scope of this post.

My question is: Is it in fact the triangles Three.js creates that cause the problem? Would making the triangles in Blender to begin with fix this problem, or is there a different approach that might fix the problem?

EDIT: Using Phong mats fixed it, but lighting seems incorrectly divided over objects individually:
[image: Point light with Phong materials in Blender and in Three.js]

Comment: three.js does not support quads. Create your model in Blender with triangles. three.js r.66.

Comment: @WestLangley I don't think that's the problem. I think the problem is that it's using MeshLambertMaterial instead of MeshPhongMaterial.

Comment: Well, did you change the material to see what happens?

Comment: @mrdoob That works partially! The objects are lighted more now, but somehow the light is poorly divided over objects. I'll add a screenshot to my main post to show what I mean.

Comment: I guess it might be the conversion to Three.js. It makes sense it's hard if not impossible to show the scene in Three.js the same way as in Blender since it's a completely different approach and platform.

Comment: Your three.js rendering does not look very good. Something is not right. Can you post a more close-up view of both -- or a live example? But first, convert to triangles first on the Blender side.

Comment: @WestLangley regarding these glitches... I bet the camera near/far values are way too big.

Comment: @mrdoob Amazing!!! My camera's 'near' value was way too small for some reason, I've set it to 1 and now everything is rendered without glitches! After some research we've decided to go with directional lighting after all to provide a more cartoon-like look. Consider this problem as solved. If there's anything I can do to help find the cause of the lighting problem I'd be happy to help. If you post the material solution I'll mark it as such.